Issues with DMG Distribution of Flutter macOS App After macOS Upgrade
I'm developing a Flutter macOS application targeted for macOS users. Previously, when my system was running macOS version 12, I was able to create a DMG file for distribution without any additional certificates or configurations. However, after upgrading to macOS 13, the DMG file I create causes issues for users trying to open the application.
The application "app_name" can't be opened.
Context:
Flutter version:3.22.2
macOS version: 13.6.4
Distribution method: DMG
Steps I’ve Taken:
flutter build macos --release 
config file is like:
{
  "title": "App name",
  "icon": "app_icon.icns",
  "contents": [
    { "x": 448, "y": 344, "type": "link", "path": "/Applications" },
    { "x": 192, "y": 344, "type": "file", "path": "../../build/macos/Build/Products/Release/appname.app" }
  ]
}

appdmg installer/dmg_creator/config.json installer/dmg_creator/appname.dmg 

Verified that the app builds successfully without errors.
Checked the app's permissions and ensured it has the necessary access.
Attempted to rebuild the DMG file multiple times.

Additional Information:
Users have reported that they see the error after double-clicking the app icon within the DMG.
I have not changed any code or configurations that worked under macOS 13.
Has anyone else experienced this issue after upgrading to macOS 13? What additional steps or configurations might be required to ensure the DMG file works properly for users?

If you do not sign your app with a developer Id certificate then the user needs to change the security settings on their Mac to disable Gatekeeper to install the app https://developer.apple.com/developer-id/

I have tried with disable gatekeeper as well as i have added signing certificate but still same issue occur
